# Angularjs ui select space representation issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I am using AngularJs UI select dropdown. As I need to represent children also in the same dropdown I am appending &nbsp to the children and the dropdown visibility is also fine. But the problem is occurring when I select a child node with &nbsp. The selected node is appearing along with &nbsp, how can I avoid those &nbsp appearance upon selection of a particular customer? Please find my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SRsAAEFLU32zlYc8JamD?p=preview) and image for reference.

As I don't want to have ugly '----', I have replaced them with '&nbsp'

```
addOptionsToDropDown(options[i].children, stringToPrepend + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp');
```

[image: ui-select]

Comment: try adding &nbsp; in {{}}. If possible the give a demo on fiddle or plunker

Comment: I have already attached the plunker.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `&nbsp;` with `String.fromCharCode(160)` .

It will work. `String.fromCharCode()` represents a string created by using the specified sequence of Unicode values. And for non-breaking space its '**160**'

I tested it by replacing

```
'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp'
```

to

```
String.fromCharCode(160)+String.fromCharCode(160)+String.fromCharCode(160)+String.fromCharCode(160)
```

in plunker its working fine.

Comment: You can do it in this way but it is all work around .. there needs to be angular solution to it

Answer (score 0):

Filter solved the issue. Plunker is updated

```
app.filter("replacenbsp", function() {
    return function(data, delimiter) {
       return data.replace('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',delimiter);
     }
   });
```

In JSP

```
{{$select.selected.name | replacenbsp : '' }}
```

Comment: You can do it in this way but it is all work around .. there needs to be angular solution to it